# How to plot scatter plot for a data in matrix form

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have data in a matrix form. I have two such matrices and want to plot it together for comparison purposes.

```
Type1:

  A B C D
A 1 2 3 4
B 2 1 7 8
C 3 7 1 9
D 4 8 9 1
```

```
Type2

  A  B  C  D
A 1  12 13 14
B 12 1  17 18
C 13 17 1  19
D 14 18 19 1
```

I want to keep type 1 as x-axis and type 2 as y-axis. How can I draw a scatter plot for this data using R?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For scatter plot you need x and y.. how is the matrix interpreted?

Comment: Scatter plot is not the correct comparison for 2 matrix, maybe you should consider another way to display the information (e.g. 2 heatmaps)

Comment: I am trying something like a Cartesian coordinate. eg: For A: (x,y). I get the x value from type1 matrix and y value from type2 matrix.

Comment: Okay there is a solution then, give me 2 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first store your matrix values into a dataframe. You can use the function `c(matrix1)` to convert your matrix into a vector then storing this vector into a dataframe.

Then you can plot each dataframe new variable against each other.

```
### Import library
library(ggplot2)

### Simulating data
df <- data.frame(
  coordinate=c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", 
               "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", 
               "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD",
               "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD"),
  matrix1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 3, 7, 1, 9, 4, 8, 9, 1),
  matrix2=c(1, 12, 13, 14, 12, 1, 17, 18, 13, 17, 1, 19, 14, 18, 19, 1))

### Display plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=matrix1, y=matrix2)) + 
  geom_point()  + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 20), breaks=seq(0, 20, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 20), breaks=seq(0, 20, 1))
```

Sometimes it makes no sense to link the dots, if so, you can remove the `geom_line()` row.

[image]

Following your second question, if you want to add labels, you have many options. You can find two options with the following code, by either using `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel` library or simply `geom_text` from `ggplot2` library where you play with `width` and `height` arguments.

```
### Update group of labels with the same coordinates
df$matrixboth <- paste(df$matrix1, df$matrix2)

### Display plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=matrix1, y=matrix2, label=coordinate)) + 
  geom_point()  + 
  geom_line(color="#6aa6e7", size=1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 20), breaks=seq(0, 20, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 20), breaks=seq(0, 20, 1)) + 
  # geom_text(position=position_jitter(width=0.6, height=0.6, aes(color=matrixboth)) + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label=coordinate, color=matrixboth)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

#### geom_text_repel

[image]

#### geom_text

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I know which points belongs to which combination? Is there a way to label it as AA, AB, BC etc?